# React - Error when import dependency that depends from another already on package.json

Tags: reactjs, npm, dependencies, circular-dependency, stealjs

On my `package.json` I have these dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@my-company-repository/componentXPTO": "19.8.5",
    "@my-company-repository/commonComponents": "18.0.2", 
    "react": "16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "16.12.0",
    "react-view-model": "^1.0.1",
    "react-virtualized": "9.21.0",
    "react-virtualized-tree": "3.1.0",
    "steal": "^2.1.11",
```

After `npm install` on `node_modules`, `@my-company-repository/componentXPTO` shows to have these dependencies:

```
"bundleDependencies": false,
"deprecated": false,
"peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@my-company-repository/commonComponents": "^17.44.6",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
```

And `@my-company-repository/commonComponents` have these:

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "react": "16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "16.12.0"
},
```

NOTE: I need both `@my-company-repository/componentXPTO` and `@my-company-repository/commonComponents`.

Then I created this component where I want to use `@my-company-repository/componentXPTO`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import FancyComponent from '@my-company-repository/componentXPTO';

class MyComponentWithFancyC extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="my-container">
        <span>some text</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponentWithFancyC;
```

If I comment the `import FancyComponent from '@my-company-repository/componentXPTO'` line everything works fine. But if I keep that line I got this red error when I access to my new component on the browser:

```
steal.js:7348 Error: Unable to parse package.json for [react]
Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

   1 | <!DOCTYPE html>
   2 | <html>
   3 |   <head lang="en">
   4 |     <meta charset="utf-8"/>
   5 |     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE"/>
   6 |     <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
   7 |     <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
   8 |     <title>My Application</title>
   9 |     <style>
  10 |       .app-loading-spinner {
  11 |         background: url(./src/main/static/images/spinner.gif);
  12 |         height: 32px;
  13 |         width: 32px;
  14 |         position: fixed;
  15 |         top: 50%;
  16 |         left: 50%;
  17 |         z-index: 999999999;
  18 |       }
  19 | 
  20 |       .app-loading-spinner-container {
  21 |         position: fixed;
  22 |         top: 0;
  23 |         left: 0;
  24 |         height: 100%;
  25 |         width: 100%;
  26 |         background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  27 |         z-index: 999999999;
  28 |       }
  29 | 
  30 |       .hide-transition {
  31 |         -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  32 |         -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  33 |         transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  34 |         opacity: 0;
  35 |       }
  36 | 
  37 |       body {
  38 |         background-color: #d8dae0;
  39 |         height: 100%;
  40 |         margin: 0;
  41 |       }
  42 | 
  43 |       html {
  44 |         height: 100%;
  45 |       }
  46 | 
  47 |       div.browser-not-supported {
  48 |         width: 100%;
  49 |         text-align: center;
  50 |         padding-top: 100px;
  51 |         font-size: x-large;
  52 |         font-family: sans-serif;
  53 |       }
  54 |     </style>
  55 |   </head>
  56 |   <body>
  57 |     <div class="app-loading-spinner-container">
  58 |       <div class="app-loading-spinner">
  59 |       </div>
  60 |     </div>
  61 |     <div id="app" class="app"></div>
  62 |     <script src="node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
  63 |     <script src="./browser-conditional-renderer.js" environment="DEVELOPMENT"></script>
  64 | 
  65 |     <!-- Company Session Management -->
  66 |     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/sessionmanagement-web/css/sessionmanagement.css">
  67 |     <script type="text/javascript" src="/sessionmanagement-web/js/ApplicationSupervision.js"></script>
  68 |   </body>
  69 | </html>
  70 | 

    at parse (node_modules/@my-company-repository/componentXPTO/node_modules/react/package.json:0)
```

Anyone knows what the problem is?

I already deleted `node_modules` and installed it again and the error remains. I already created a new blank react project where I only use `@my-company-repository/componentXPTO` (without having `@my-company-repository/componentXPTO` on `package.json`) dependency and it works fine.

I have no clue about how to solve this...

Comment: Usually `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` errors mean that an HTML file (usually a 404 page) is being loaded instead of the package.json file. Can you look in the Network tab of DevTools and see what path steal is trying to load react from?

Comment: @ChasenLeHara thanks for the tip but the problem was already solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out.

Initially it seems `@my-company-repository/componentXPTO/node_modules/@my-company-repository/commonComponents` has causing the problem looking for the `react` at `@my-company-repository/componentXPTO/node_modules/` folder. But `react` don't exists there because it is a `peerDependency`.

So I needed to remap that through the StealJS. For that, in my `package.json` I added a StealJS configuration:

```
"steal": {
    "paths": {
      "@my-company-repository/componentXPTO/node_modules/react/*": "node_modules/react/*.js",
      "@my-company-repository/componentXPTO/node_modules/react-dom/*": "node_modules/react-dom/*.js"
    }
```

After that some other problems came but because having a dependency also as dependency of another dependency. So I deleted that dependency from the other dependency. For that I created a `postInstall.js` file on my root folder with the following code:

```
const pj = __dirname + "/node_modules/@my-company-repository/componentXPTO/package.json";
const contents = fs.readFileSync(pj);
const pkg = JSON.parse(contents);
delete pkg.dependencies["@my-company-repository/commonComponents"];
fs.writeFileSync(pj, JSON.stringify(pkg));
```

And then I added a script to my `package.json` to run this new code after `npm install`:

```
"scripts": {
    "install": "node postInstall"
```

Now `@my-company-repository/componentXPTO` shows to have these dependencies:

```
"bundleDependencies": false,
"deprecated": false,
"peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0"
},
"dependencies": {
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
```

And the other dependencies of this one looks for `react` at my project `node_modules` folder.